# R Order group of names based on condition

Tags: r

I'm trying to put group names together order them, while letting the position of the other names depends on the order mentioned above above.

Let's say I have the following names

```
 a <- c("zz", "CountryA", "CountryC", "xy", "aa","CountryB")
```

and I want to order the Country together to give the following output.

```
c("zz", "CountryA", "CountryB", "CountryC", "xy", "aa")
```

I got the results above from the following function.

```
orderGroup <- function(regex,char) {
### purpose
     ## order by group leaving the rest unchanged
    group <- grep(regex,char,value=TRUE)
    orderGroup <- group[order(group)]

    indexGroup <-  grep(regex,char)
    indexNotInGroup <-  grep(paste0("^[^",regex,"]"),char)

    c(char[indexNotInGroup[indexNotInGroup<min(indexGroup)]],
      orderGroup,char[indexNotInGroup[indexNotInGroup>min(orderc)]])
 }
```

usage:

```
orderGroup("Country",a)
```

From this point I have 1 question:

- Do you have a better way of doing this. I have not tested the function except on the above so I'm sure there are cases to add and some tuning to do.

Comment: Granted. Edited, the example, hope it makes ideas clearer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
patt = "^Country"

cs = grep(patt, a)
append(a[-cs], sort(a[cs]), after = cs[1]-1)
# "zz"       "CountryA" "CountryB" "CountryC" "xy"       "aa"
```

It is not substantially different from the OP's function, though.

Comment: Yours is much more compact and easy to grasp though. I haven't used the function append before. Will keep it in mind thanks.

Comment: @Frank Nice one (+1).  But, it would be better to specify the `after=` .  I noticed only after reading the description.

Comment: @akrun Agreed, thanks. Yeah, whenever I guess how to pass by position to `append`, I get it wrong, thinking it's like `append(x, position, y)`.